# Android Marshmallow: How to allow Runtime Permissions programatically?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-uiautomator, runtime-permissions

I'm developing an app that require some system permissions, however these are no longer granted automatically at installation time on Android Marshmallow.

I would like to request these permissions at runtime and run some kind of automation to grant them without needing a user to tap the 'allow' button when the System permissions Dialog appears.

How can I achieve this? Is there any way to do so in Marshmallow and later versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Marshmallow or later permissions are not granted at install time and must be requested when required at runtime (if not granted previously.)

To do this, you need to run `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` to pop up the systems permissions dialog in your Activity, at the time when the user is undertaking an action that requires additional system permissions.

An example of this for the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission would be:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    this, 
    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
    WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE
);
```

Note: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE` is an arbitrary integer constant you should define elsewhere.

The permissions you request should also be declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. In this example the declaration would be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In order to handle the system permissions dialog response you will also need to implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in your Activity. For this example the code would be similar to

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        return; //permission not granted, could also optionally log an error
    }
    if (requestCode == WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        //Do whatever you needed the write permissions for            
    }
}
```

If you are automating your app through [Espresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/), [UIAutomator](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/) and/or some other UI testing framework you will need to anticipate and click the system dialog during your test, which can be accomplished with the following test code:

```
private void allowPermissionsIfNeeded()  {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        UiObject allowPermissions = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Allow"));
        if (allowPermissions.exists()) {
            try {
                allowPermissions.click();
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "There is no permissions dialog to interact with ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A more comprehensive explanation of testing System UI Permissions is available [here](https://medium.com/exploring-android/handling-android-runtime-permissions-in-ui-tests-981f9dc11a4e#.ec4h9tltt).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, though I need only the last part after 'Espresso'. By the way I'm not automating my app through 'Espresso', I'm just clicking buttons and controlling app flow from within the app. Is it possible to do so without using anything like 'Espresso'?

Comment: You're welcome :) What exactly are you trying to automate and for what purpose? How are you doing this currently? It's a little unclear what you're trying to achieve (or what you mean by "clicking" buttons from within the app) from the question description.

Comment: That simply means whenever I want to click button1, I execute button1.performClick(). So, likewise is there any way to click 'Allow' in System Dialog whenever my app asks for permission?

Comment: In simple words, I want to grant permissions internally, without any user interaction.

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of asking the user for permissions and constitute a security vulnerability - the only way to automate this kind of interaction is by controlling the device outside of the app itself (typically using some kind of Instrumentation/UI testing framework.)

Comment: Also, in terms of clicking the "button" programmatically a better way would be to have a utility method that is called in the onClick method of the button (that you can call elsewhere in the program). Triggering functionality by faking a button press is a bit convoluted (not to mention difficult to unit test effectively). You may wish to consider MVP architecture - your Activity more or less should only handle interface mechanics, separating business logic into a separate Presenter class.

Comment: Why do you want to trigger the button press? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve overall in a bit more detail?

Comment: Yeah, that will definitely defeat the purpose of Runtime Permissions. And typical way to do so is to use some kind of Instrumentation/UI testing framework. But I don't know that, so I decided to go for internal click events. Moreover, I need very few clicks to achieve my goal. So, I chose this. But I got stuck at this part(allowing permissions). I think I'll have to go for "Instrumentation/UI testing framework" then.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what your goal is - if you outline that further there may be other options. Also, if you're happy with the answer please accept and upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that an simpler way to automate the permission acceptance without using UIAutomator or espresso in a CI scenario is to simply, pre-installing the apk via adb using:

```
adb install -g {my_apk_file}
```

The -g flag automatically grants all manifest permissions to the app. Afterwards if you launch your espresso test suite, the ui won't ask you again to grant them.

Comment: This helped me in SuperUser mode